# Calcular prom- arreglos PSEINT

Tags: pseint

tengo un problema con mi código en PSeint, tengo que leer 10 usuarios, con su identificación, tener sus 3 notas y hacerle un promedio para mostrar en pantalla. sin embargo, cuando estoy ingresando las notas me salen las mismas y no aparecen los diferentes valores, ¡alguien podria ayudarme a resolver este problema?

```
Algoritmo taller_5
    Definir cedula,x,notas,notaa,promedio Como Real;
    Definir nombre Como Caracter;
    i=1;
    Dimension nombre[10], cedula[10], nota[10];
    promedio=0;
    Escribir " Bienvenidos a la plataforma de estudiantes de Ingeniería de la unidad temática LOGICA Y ALGORITMIA";
    Para x=1 Hasta 10 con paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "==================================";
        Escribir i," Digite el nombre del estudiante";
        leer nombre(x);
        Escribir i," Digite la cedula del estudiante";
        Leer cedula(x);
        Para notas=1 Hasta 3 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Escribir i," Digite la nota del estudiante";
            Leer nota(x);
        FinPara
        i<-i+1;
    FinPara
    Para x=1 Hasta 10 con paso 1 Hacer
        i=1;
        promedio = (nota[1]+[2]+[3])/3;
        Escribir "=============================================";
        Escribir "El nombre del estudiante ",i," es: ",nombre(x);
        Escribir "La cedula es: ",cedula(x);
        Escribir "Nota parcial: ",nota(x);
        Escribir "Nota parcial: ",nota(x);
        Escribir "Nota parcial: ",nota(x);
        Escribir "La nota del estudiante es: ",promedio;
        i<-i+1;
    FinPara
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás sobrescribiendo el valor de la posición `x` de la matriz (arreglo) `nota[10]` cada vez que entras al segundo `Para`. Por ejemplo, cuando `x` vale `1` y se ejecuta la línea `Leer nota(x)` y el valor ingresado de la nota es `80`, se guarda en `nota(1)` PERO cuando el `Para` interno se vuelve a ejecutar, guarda la nueva nota ingresada también en `nota(1)` y el valor anterior, `80`, se pierde. Algo similar pasa en el segundo `Para` donde sacas los promedios, estás siempre sacando el promedio de las tres primeras posiciones de `nota[]` y eso nunca va a cambiar.

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una matriz bidimensional `notas[10, 3]` donde por cada fila (número de estudiantes) haya 3 columnas (notas). Igual es buena idea usar variables para el número de estudiantes y de notas, así se hace más dinámico.

Ahora cuando guardes un alumno, guardarás las notas en el mismo número de fila que corresponde con la posición del estudiante dentro de la matriz `notas[]`. Es decir, si el contador de tu primer `Para` es `i` y el del `Para` interno es `j`, deberás guardar las notas en el `Para` interno como `Leer notas[i, j];`.

Igual cuando sacas el promedio, puedes irlo sumando en el mismo `Para` que se usa para imprimir las notas, al final lo divides entre el número de notas y lo reinicias a `0`.

```
Algoritmo taller_5
    Definir cedula, notas, promedio, numero_estudiantes, numero_notas Como Real;
    Definir nombre Como Caracter;
    
    numero_estudiantes = 10;
    numero_notas = 3;
    
    Dimension nombre[numero_estudiantes], cedula[numero_estudiantes];
    Dimension notas[numero_estudiantes, numero_notas];
    
    Escribir "Bienvenidos a la plataforma de estudiantes de Ingeniería de la unidad temática LOGICA Y ALGORITMIA";
    Para i=1 Hasta numero_estudiantes con paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "==================================";
        Escribir i," Digite el nombre del estudiante";
        Leer nombre[i];
        Escribir i," Digite la cedula del estudiante";
        Leer cedula[i];
        Para j=1 Hasta numero_notas Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Escribir i, ".", j," Digite la nota del estudiante";
            Leer notas[i, j];
        FinPara
    FinPara
    
    Para i=1 Hasta numero_estudiantes con paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "=============================================";
        Escribir "El nombre del estudiante ", i, " es: ", nombre[i];
        Escribir "La cedula es: ", cedula[i];
        Para j=1 Hasta numero_notas Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Escribir "Nota parcial: ", notas[i, j];
            promedio = promedio + notas[i, j];
        Fin Para
        Escribir "La nota del estudiante es: ", promedio/numero_notas;
        promedio = 0;
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```